# Application exited with code -1072365566 (0xc0150002)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I've statically linked a lib compiled via VS2005 with my program which also compiled via VS2005 and it runs fine. But others who before used the program can't run it now, they are getting error `Application exited with code -1072365566 (0xc0150002)`. I have no idea what can be the reason of failure and seems google also hasn't. What can be the reason of such behavior?

Comment: Typically because you didn't deploy the CRT dlls or deployed an old version.  Look in the Windows event log for the diagnostic.

Comment: It looks like an access violation error

Comment: @Pramod - incorrect, that would be 0xc0000005.  Hans's advice is probably on the right lines.  Static libs and VS2005 service releases do not mix well in my experience.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. But how can I fix the problem should I build the lib with some special flags?

Comment: The `0002` indicates an OS error 2, `file not found`. This is typically caused when a DLL is being loaded and in turn requires another DLL, which the loader can't find. As @Hans said, check the event log, or use ProcessMonitor or DependencyWalker to figure out what you're forgetting to distribute.

Comment: @Hans: Yes your suggestion is right the problem is follows:
Error in manifest or policy file "" on line . A component version required by the application conflicts with another component version already active. Conflicting components are:. Component 1: (home_of_my_application)\bin\Microsoft.VC80.CRT\Microsoft.VC80.CRT.MANIFEST. Component 2: C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4927_none_d08a205e442db5b5.manifest